# showing web pages on facebook

Tags: facebook

I want to develop Facebook pages and tabs like the following  where i can pull data from my web site.

http://www.facebook.com/AppStore?v=app_133863019976324&ref=ts and http://www.facebook.com/Savings?v=app_4949752878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sign up as a Facebook developer, download the example code, read the documentation and implement the site then. Facebook make it really easy.

Comment: at one point it asked me to **download the Facebook library (through wget) and extract the files in this archive via gunzip and tar** Now how do i do this if i access my server files through ftp in windows

Comment: probably by doing what i did and looking this up on google or going to the facebook help page and working it out. winzip should undo the archive or winrar